# About app.run() in different version in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

So in ASP.NET Core 2.x version, the following middleware runs without a problem.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("HAHA");
});
```

But in .NET 6 the program somehow just exits with code 0 after I run it, anyone knows why? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Ideally we'd be able to drop this in a brand new app on our computers and reproduce your issue.